# PWA push notifications not working when app is not installed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

Are push notification supposed to work only if the PWA is installed?
If I load the app in android chrome browser, push notifications are not displayed at all (background or having the site opened) even they come thru the wire.

If I install the app, all notifications are displayed properly (background or focused app).

Is this normal a behaviour or something wrong in the implementation?

Answer (score 4):

This is as expected.

The service worker runs on a separate thread than the one used by your application. This is the reason why your web app can still receive and display notifications even if you (or your user) is not currently visiting the web site.

Therefore if the PWA is not installed (meaning the SW is not running on the client side), there is no code waiting for the incoming notifications.

[I wrote an article about service workers](https://dev.to/paco_ita/service-workers-and-caching-strategies-explained-step-3-m4f), if you want to deepen the  PWAs topic.

---

**UPDATE**

- There is an [article specifically from OneSignal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/notifications-show-successful-but-are-not-being-shown) about not receiving Push Notifications on Android, maybe you can find some hints. If you check the OneSignal dashboard, can you see your client registered there?
- [**This point is for other users landing to this question**]
   If your browser does not show web notifications, you can verify on "Can I Use" web site that your browser version supports [notifications](https://caniuse.com/#search=Notifications) and [push API](https://caniuse.com/#search=push) and eventually update it.

Comment: Even with browser opened, page loaded and browser focused, notifications are not displayed at all on android chrome. Is that normal?

Comment: If you test the app on a desktop, you can use Chrome Dev Tools > Application Tab > Service Workers Item. Here you can check if the SW is installed and running and you can test Push Notifications with the "Push" input field. The field accept a Notification object. However you do not have this field available if no SW is active and running. If you do not have a SW you cannot test locally Push Notifications (even with the browser opened and on focus).

Comment: But I do have SW up and running on android chrome but notifications are not displayed unless I install the app.

Comment: How do you send the notifications: did you implement a server part or do you use a 3rd party service? Or are you trying to test the notification using Chrome dev tools?

Comment: I'm using OneSignal for everything and the messages are sent from their UI. Just wanted to know if this a normal behaviour or there's something wrong in my implementation. If it's not an expected behaviour then I will further investigate my implementation but seems that no one can give me a straight answer to this question...

Comment: I read that article before but I couldn't find a solution. I just wanted to know if that's a normal behaviour or not. The case i'm dealing with is very specific so I suppose someone with more experience than me can confirm it or not. It's the first time when I'm implementing something like this and it's quite hard to know which is an expected behaviour or not.

Answer (score 0):

In short, this is abnormal, push notification should work once the service worker is registered no matter if PWA is installed. All you have to be aware are the service worker registration and push event handling.

[Service Worker Push API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API)

> For an app to receive push messages, it has to have an active service
> worker. When the service worker is active, it can subscribe to push
> notifications, using PushManager.subscribe().

```js
// example of service-worker.js 
// can receive push notification from server even PWA not installed

self.addEventListener('push', (event) => {
    // Parse the notification payload (assuming it's in JSON format)
    const { toPage, title, body, icon } = event.data.json();
    let iconResult
    const options = {
        // Customize the notification here

        actions: [
            { action: toPage, title: 'Visit ' + toPage.toUpperCase() },
        ],
        icon: icon || undefined,
        body, // The content of the notification
        title, // The title of the notification
        vibrate: [200, 100, 200], // Vibration pattern for supported devices (optional)
        toPage
        // Other options like actions, renotify, requireInteraction, etc.
    };

    // Show the notification to the user
    event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));
});
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
    // Get the URL to navigate to (in this case, '/home')
    const urlToOpen = new URL(`${event.action || 'index'}.html`, self.location.origin).href;

    // Prevent other listeners from handling the event
    event.notification.close();

    // Open a new window/tab with the specified URL
    event.waitUntil(clients.openWindow(urlToOpen));
});
```